# Crash on write file procedure !closed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash, cocos2d-x

I write a procedure tha must to write 2d-array to a file. Here's code:

```
void Level::loadLevel(){
    int levelmap[15][9];
    FILE *fp = fopen("resources/lvls/loc1.map", "wb");  
    for (int i=0;i<=15;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
            levelmap[i][j]=i+j;
            }
    }
    char asd[255];

    for (int i=0;i<=15;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
            char *buffer=itoa(levelmap[i][j],asd,1);
            fwrite(buffer,2,sizeof(buffer),fp);
            };
        };
    fclose(fp);
 }
```

it's compiling, but on call this function application is crashed. i call it as `menu_selector` attribute of cocs2d-x menu item. Why is it crashes?

Update: Changed to file streams ad works excellent

Comment: Is the file really opened? Check the return value of `fopen`. You also index your arrays one to many in your loops.

Comment: How does it crash? What exception is thrown? Which line is faulty? Have you tried to debug this code?

Comment: yep, it's opened. file cleared and closed. tried this code:
      void Level::loadLevel(){
     FILE* fp = fopen("resources/lvls/loc1.map", "w+");
     fwrite("test",1,sizeof("test"),fp);
     fclose(fp);}


but it's return `Run-Time Check Failure #0`

Comment: you cannot write to apk files. you can only write to sdcard (if you have the permision) or the getWriteablePath() in CCFileUltis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *buffer=itoa(levelmap[i][j],asd,1);
```

The last param of itoa is base. It should be 10 instead of 1 (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/ )

---

```
void Level::loadLevel(){
    int levelmap[15][9];
    FILE *fp = fopen("resources/lvls/loc1.map", "wb");  
    for (int i=0;i<=15;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
            levelmap[i][j]=i+j;
            }
    }
```

If i == 15 and j == 9, you exceed array's boundaries (levelmap[15][9] means levelmap[0..14][0..8])

Change conditions in loops to i < 15 and j < 9.

Comment: `Run-Time Check Failure #0`

Comment: but at last file was changed

Comment: ok, i think it's resolved. now trouble with libcoco2d, which return `run-rime check failure #0`. I think it's all because it's non-cocos function

Comment: I did not understand. What do you mean?

Comment: My answer was downvoted by someone (not necessarily you). I would like to know, why.

Answer (score 3):

Not only the mistake mentioned above...

1. Make sure your folder "resources/lvls/" does exist. fopen doesn't create folders!
2. third parameter of itoa - radix (Base of value; which must be in the **range 2–36**.)
3. Do you really want to write it as string representation of int in binary format? Openning file for binary output means that you'll write there raw data. You can use next code to save and load int array to/from file:

'

```
void saveLevel()
{
    int levelmap[15][9];
    FILE *fp = fopen("loc1.map", "wb");  
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            levelmap[i][j]=i+j;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        fwrite(levelmap[i], sizeof(int), _countof(levelmap[i]), fp);
    };

    fclose(fp);
}

void loadLevel()
{
    int levelmap[15][9];

    FILE *fp = fopen("loc1.map", "rb");  

    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        fread(levelmap[i], sizeof(int), _countof(levelmap[i]), fp);
    };
    fclose(fp);

}
```

'

Comment: you reading only `[i]`  array level and didn't place it back to `levelmap`. if i will assign that fread text would it return whole `[j]` array level?

Comment: One dimension array in C++ is a solid memory bloc. So you can just read and write the whole array with one line of code, but you can't do it with array of classes that contains dynamically alocated field... You just need to understand how objects are placed in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding your array boundaries in a couple places so you are corrupting memory.  For example:

```
int levelmap[15][9];
//           ^^  ^

// ...

for (int i=0;i<=15;i++){
    //        ^^^^
    for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
                 ^^^
        levelmap[i][j]=i+j;
    }
}
```

Using `<=` in a `for` loop condition for array indexes is a red flag. It's nearly always the wrong thing to do, so check the code carefully whenever you see it.

Also:

```
char *buffer= /* ... */;
// ...
fwrite(buffer,2,sizeof(buffer),fp);
```

doesn't do what you think it does, since `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, which has nothing to do with the number of characters in the buffer.  And why are you passing `2` as the size of the element to `fwrite()`?

Comment: i just increased size of my array. Thank you. But it's not exact crasher